# How can I fix the create-react-app build error?

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app

I have problem build with create-react-app(version 1 ) in windows.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src node scripts/start.js",
"build": "node scripts/build.js",
"test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
```

},

Build error is here.

[image: build error messages]

```
build script link is here : 
 https://github.com/desiresprout/nettour/blob/master/nettour- 
frontend/scripts/build.js

webpack prod link is here : 
https://github.com/desiresprout/nettour/blob/master/nettour- 
frontend/config/webpack.config.prod.js
```

There is nothing to change create-react-app.

I don't know why it's wrong.

thanks..

Comment: are you creating a new app using create-react-app?

Comment: Are you asking me to create a new product?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether you are facing this issue with a new app which you are trying to create using create-react-app

Comment: It was a project being made.

Comment: I've inlined the image. Please [edit] your post and put the error message _as text_ into your post!